# Codelite Shows The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: mingw, codelite

I am a beginner using and learning c, I'm having problems with my IDE CodeLite. Whenever i run my programm it shows

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c cd H:\aniketjhariya\cmake-build-debug\ani && C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j2 SHELL=cmd.exe -e

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What should I do, please help?

Comment: CodeLite is an editor. It seems you are missing the actual compiler (mingw)

Comment: If you're learning C why did you tag this question with C++? These are two different languages.